# Naas.link problems with Run

Tags: chainlink

Anyone playing on Naas.link? Setup my node. deployed an Oracle Contract. connected the node to the oracle. created a get>uint256. created the atestnetconsumer, but can't get it to run. and my current price just stays at zero

job specs in toml, but I didn't know how to insert toml so i used javascript option

```js
type = "directrequest"
schemaVersion = 1
name = "Get > Uint256"
# Optional External Job ID: Automatically generated if unspecified
# externalJobID = "b1d42cd5-4a3a-4200-b1f7-25a68e48aad8"
contractAddress = "YOUR_ORACLE_CONTRACT_ADDRESS"
maxTaskDuration = "0s"
observationSource = """
    decode_log   [type="ethabidecodelog"
                  abi="OracleRequest(bytes32 indexed specId, address requester, bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddr, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 cancelExpiration, uint256 dataVersion, bytes data)"
                  data="$(jobRun.logData)"
                  topics="$(jobRun.logTopics)"]

    decode_cbor  [type="cborparse" data="$(decode_log.data)"]
    fetch        [type="http" method=GET url="$(decode_cbor.get)"]
    parse        [type="jsonparse" path="$(decode_cbor.path)" data="$(fetch)"]
    multiply     [type="multiply" input="$(parse)" times=100]
    encode_data  [type="ethabiencode" abi="(uint256 value)" data="{ \\"value\\": $(multiply) }"]
    encode_tx    [type="ethabiencode"
                  abi="fulfillOracleRequest(bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddress, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 expiration, bytes32 data)"
                  data="{\\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"payment\\": $(decode_log.payment), \\"callbackAddress\\": $(decode_log.callbackAddr), \\"callbackFunctionId\\": $(decode_log.callbackFunctionId), \\"expiration\\": $(decode_log.cancelExpiration), \\"data\\": $(encode_data)}"
                 ]
    submit_tx    [type="ethtx" to="YOUR_ORACLE_CONTRACT_ADDRESS" data="$(encode_tx)"]

    decode_log -> decode_cbor -> fetch -> parse -> multiply -> encode_data -> encode_tx -> submit_tx
"""
```

here's the kovan etherscan hash:

0x2db26a43becadb046fa2bec8dc3466729b17c39406f88c2888f33c0447eef163

here's the consumer contract

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ConfirmedOwner.sol";

contract ATestnetConsumer is ChainlinkClient, ConfirmedOwner {
  using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;

  uint256 constant private ORACLE_PAYMENT = 1 * LINK_DIVISIBILITY;
  uint256 public currentPrice;
  int256 public changeDay;
  bytes32 public lastMarket;

  event RequestEthereumPriceFulfilled(
    bytes32 indexed requestId,
    uint256 indexed price
  );

  event RequestEthereumChangeFulfilled(
    bytes32 indexed requestId,
    int256 indexed change
  );

  event RequestEthereumLastMarket(
    bytes32 indexed requestId,
    bytes32 indexed market
  );

  constructor() ConfirmedOwner(msg.sender){
    setPublicChainlinkToken();
  }

  function requestEthereumPrice(address _oracle, string memory _jobId)
    public
    onlyOwner
  {
    Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(stringToBytes32(_jobId), address(this), this.fulfillEthereumPrice.selector);
    req.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=USD");
    req.add("path", "USD");
    req.addInt("times", 100);
    sendChainlinkRequestTo(_oracle, req, ORACLE_PAYMENT);
  }

  function requestEthereumChange(address _oracle, string memory _jobId)
    public
    onlyOwner
  {
    Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(stringToBytes32(_jobId), address(this), this.fulfillEthereumChange.selector);
    req.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD");
    req.add("path", "RAW.ETH.USD.CHANGEPCTDAY");
    req.addInt("times", 1000000000);
    sendChainlinkRequestTo(_oracle, req, ORACLE_PAYMENT);
  }

  function requestEthereumLastMarket(address _oracle, string memory _jobId)
    public
    onlyOwner
  {
    Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(stringToBytes32(_jobId), address(this), this.fulfillEthereumLastMarket.selector);
    req.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD");
    string[] memory path = new string[](4);
    path[0] = "RAW";
    path[1] = "ETH";
    path[2] = "USD";
    path[3] = "LASTMARKET";
    req.addStringArray("path", path);
    sendChainlinkRequestTo(_oracle, req, ORACLE_PAYMENT);
  }

  function fulfillEthereumPrice(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _price)
    public
    recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
  {
    emit RequestEthereumPriceFulfilled(_requestId, _price);
    currentPrice = _price;
  }

  function fulfillEthereumChange(bytes32 _requestId, int256 _change)
    public
    recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
  {
    emit RequestEthereumChangeFulfilled(_requestId, _change);
    changeDay = _change;
  }

  function fulfillEthereumLastMarket(bytes32 _requestId, bytes32 _market)
    public
    recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
  {
    emit RequestEthereumLastMarket(_requestId, _market);
    lastMarket = _market;
  }

  function getChainlinkToken() public view returns (address) {
    return chainlinkTokenAddress();
  }

  function withdrawLink() public onlyOwner {
    LinkTokenInterface link = LinkTokenInterface(chainlinkTokenAddress());
    require(link.transfer(msg.sender, link.balanceOf(address(this))), "Unable to transfer");
  }

  function cancelRequest(
    bytes32 _requestId,
    uint256 _payment,
    bytes4 _callbackFunctionId,
    uint256 _expiration
  )
    public
    onlyOwner
  {
    cancelChainlinkRequest(_requestId, _payment, _callbackFunctionId, _expiration);
  }

  function stringToBytes32(string memory source) private pure returns (bytes32 result) {
    bytes memory tempEmptyStringTest = bytes(source);
    if (tempEmptyStringTest.length == 0) {
      return 0x0;
    }

    assembly { // solhint-disable-line no-inline-assembly
      result := mload(add(source, 32))
    }
  }
```

the tutorial tells me to put in the address of the network I'm using (kovan). It says there should be an input field next to the deploy button. But there is no input field.

here's the link to the tutorial

https://docs.chain.link/docs/fulfilling-requests/

I stopped here.

Comment: To help properly troubleshoot this with you it require some extra info: 
1. Your JobSpec in TOML format (or JSON if you're using the deprecated JSON jobs).      
2. Your oracle contact, confirmed on Etherscan, so I can check that everything has been properly deployed and set there. 
3. The solidity code for your "Consumer" contract (the contract making the API call).

If you could edit your question with those bits of info,  I or someone else should be able to help you.

Comment: thanks for answering. No detail lol just shows how lost I am. not too sure what to even include in the these questions.

Comment: I just updated the question with the info.

Comment: Thanks for this, great job in figuring all that info out. One last question, did you deploy an Oracle.sol contract and fill set the fulfillPermissions function with your node address? The oracle contract is the contract that represents your node on-chain and is separate from the consumer contract.
The oracle contract is can be seen here: https://remix.ethereum.org/#url=https://docs.chain.link/samples/NodeOperators/Oracle.sol&optimize=false&runs=200&evmVersion=null&version=soljson-v0.8.7+commit.e28d00a7.js

This is the contract being referred to with the address next to the deploy button.

Comment: Yes I deployed the Oracle contract and pressed the fullifllPersmissions with my node address. It's a chainlink tutorial and I think something is missing. I followed the instructions but it says to put in the network address but there is no parameter field for the constructor(This on the ATestnetConsumer.sol)

Comment: node_address, true

Comment: I don't think they are referring to the Oracle contract address.

Comment: Select "Injected Web3" as your environment.
Select "ATestnetConsumer" from the Contract menu.
Copy the address for the network you are using and paste it into the address_link field next to the Deploy button.

Comment: I think the oracle address and the jobID is input when you call the function on the deployed ATestnetConsumer.sol as a parameter.

Comment: @ZakAyesh any thoughts about the new comments. The ATestnetConsumer.sol does not have any parameters in the constructor.